# My Universal Windows Platform Application crashs when I click menu items

Tags: c#, uwp

I made the Icons of my menu Items using `FontIcon` and I write 'Segoe Fluent Icons' In the `FontFamily` section and use It. But when I click on my menu Items, my app crashes. I downloaded the 'Segoe Fluent Icons' font package from Microsoft's site and tried It, but when I restart my PC, the same problem happens again.

My Menu Items Code:

```cs
<muxc:MenuBar>
     <muxc:MenuBarItem Title="Example">
          <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item1">
               <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                     <FontIcon Glyph="&#xF6FA" FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons"/>
               </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
          </MenuFlyoutItem>
     </muxc:MenuBarItem>
</muxc:MenuBar>
```

Comment: Please share some of your code so we can help you better

Comment: Why do you think that the font is the problem? I’m not saying it isn’t, but it would be helpful to know what’s led you to this conclusion. Given that the icons display and don’t cause a problem until thye are clicked, my first idea would be that there is a problem with handler code.

Comment: I've added my code. Sorry

Comment: Does the problem go away if you remove the FontIcon element? That would help isolate whether the font is the problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes the problem goes away but sets the font family "Segoe MDL2 Assets Icons" by default. But I want to set "Segoe Fluent Icons".

Comment: Did you install the font after downloading it? It's not clear what you mean when you said you "tried it", and you didn't say whether your "try" was successful.

Comment: Instead of installing the font, you can package it with your app, and use a font file reference. https://blog.mzikmund.com/2017/01/using-custom-fonts-in-cs-uwp-apps/

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, successfully installed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, it seems that you are missing a semicolon for the value of **Glyph** property. After adding it, the code could run correctly and the Icon will show.

Code here:

```
                <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xF6FA;" FontFamily="Segoe Fluent Icons"/>
                </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Although it's not mentioned in MSFT documentation, the semicolon solves it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.fonticon.glyph?view=winrt-22621

Comment: It's not mentioned because the semicolon is just part of XML syntax. It's like not mentioning that your closing tags have to be matched to the open tags.

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot to add a semicolon here. My code has a semicolon. Here's my problem:
The icons come up and it works fine at first but when I restart my app, app crashes. I'm sorry if I couldn't tell.

Comment: @AlperAkca Please try to reproduce this issue in a blank project. And share the sample here. So we could help to troubleshoot this better.

Comment: @AlperAkca Could you please share a sample that could reproduce this? Using the code you posted, the sample works correctly.

Comment: My App running fine at first run. But when I restart my PC app crashes. I can take screen recording if you want.

Comment: @AlperAkca Can you reproduce this behavior now your device now?